# Establecer login de sesion que evite la entrada de usuario no logueados previamente

Tags: php, session

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación web y quiero que antes de acceder  a ella me obligue a pasar por el menú de registro y entonces loguearme. Actualmente cuando entro en el index.php directamente me deja acceder a el y tengo que cerrar sesión para acceder al menú de login.

index.php

```
 <?php 
    session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
        header("location: index.php");
    }

     //sino entoces buscamos los datos en a BD
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {        
      header("location: register.php");

     }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar más detalles y más partes de tu codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Tu estas consultando si la sesion user existe redireccioname a index.php para que eso devuelva TRUE deberias de definir una sesion una linea arriba.
y si lo que quieres es que si la sesion es diferente de user entonces 
te redireccion al inicio

```
$_SESSION['user']= "";

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
header("location: index.php");
}
```

Segun lo que solicitas en el Mensaje de abajo
Dentro de nuestra carpeta del proyecto crearemos nuestro index.php, dentro de este archivo colocaremos las dependencias e iniciaremos la sesión del cliente para posteriormente asignarle un nombre.

```
<?php
session_start();
include(‘includes/conexion.php‘);
include(‘includes/sesion.php‘);
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select * from usuarios where correo='$correo'")or die('Error en la sesion');
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Bienvenido</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Bienvenido <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Conexion.php

```
  <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","base de datos");
// checamos la conexion
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Error al conectarse con MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

SESION.php

```
<?php
// Iniciamos la sesion
session_start();
//// Verifica si la variable de sesión SESS_MEMBER_ID está presente o no
if (!isset($_SESSION['correo']) || (trim($_SESSION['correo']) == '')) {
header("location: entrar.php");
exit();
}
$correo=$_SESSION['correo'];
?>
```

Comment: Lo que quiero es que al entrar directamente en el index.php, me mande al menú registro.php, ya que no tengo ningun usuario logueado, una vez logueado permitirme ir al index.php

Comment: Lo que deberias de hacer es
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
header("location: registro.php");
}

Comment: Con eso que comentas me lleva al register.php pero no me permite loguearme, he puesto el register.php, a ver si puedes mirar qué tengo mal.

Comment: Donde esta el codigo, no lo veo